# Expandable vs Expansible vs Scalable

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

My lexicon says:

- `Expandable` adj  (device: can extend)
- `Expansible` adj  (able to expand)
- `Scalable`   adj  figurative (technology: able to expand)

I want to use one of this terms to say that my software application can be modified at will, add new, remove and/or change existing functionalities, which term is more suitable to use (and why) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Scalable" is often used with software applications, but it usually has a definite meaning: an app is said to be "scalable" if it can handle ten records, a million records or a trillion records without slowing down much (or crashing!). For example, the software running Google had to be scalable since it handles so *much* data.

"Expandable" is used when the software can have new features added by the user: for example, the core word processor has an English-only dictionary, but it can be expanded with an Italian, Chinese or Polish dictionary.

"Expansible" may have that definition, but it is an uncommon word: I wouldn't use it.

I personally would use "extendable". That is similar in meaning to "expandable", but it implies that it can be extended in many different ways.

Comment: +1, but there is also *extendable* vs. *extensible*. Extendable referring to physical properties (an *extendable ladder*) and extensible referring to versatility/ability to be added to in future (an *extensible system*).

Answer (score 1):

Given the source code, all software can be modified. You need to think about how your software can be modified. Is your software modular? Can you extend the functionality by adding new modules or extensions (plug-ins). You could say that your software is extendable using plug-in modules (providing that it is).

[Scalable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability) has a different meaning in software engineering and you should probably avoid the term in this context.